# Weak or Unowned or None

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, unowned-references

I have a ViewController class as shown below:

```
class ViewController {

    var viewModel = ViewModel()

    viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewModel.showAlert = { [weak self] in
            self?.alert()
        }
    }

    func alert() {
        // alert logic
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel class

```
class ViewModel {
    var showAlert: (() -> Void)?
}
```

Now, does this create a strong reference cycle or not?

And if this creates one, then what to use - weak or unowned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does **not** create a strong reference cycle, because you used `weak self`.

`ViewController` holds a strong reference to `ViewModel`. `ViewModel` holds a strong reference to a closure. The closure holds a *weak* reference to the `ViewController`:

```
VC ---strong---> ViewModel
 ^                    |
 |                   strong
 |                    v
  --------weak-----closure
```

As long as `ViewController` is deallocated (this happens when you dismiss it for example),  `ViewModel` will be as well.

Comment: if weak is not used then there is a strong reference cycle, Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks. And what is preferable here? Weak or unowned? I think ViewModel and ViewController both have same lifetime so it's safe to use unowned instead of weak. Your thoughts?

Comment: @SavanKavaiya yeah I suppose. Note that if something else is holding a strong reference to the closure, you should use weak, since the closure can exist without the VC.